# Avoir un bol de cocu

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

J'aimerais connaître l'origine du sens de cette phrase.

- De quel bol s'agit-il ?
- Et pourquoi les cocus en auraient-ils plus que les
  autres?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Le bol

Le *bol* est ici synonyme de *chance*. Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org) donne une explication pour l'origine de cette expression

> En ancien français, le bol et le pot désignaient également le derrière mais ces expressions sont passées dans le langage familier.<sup>[Wikt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_du_bol#.C3.89tymologie)</sup>

*[Avoir du bol](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_du_bol#.C3.89tymologie)*, c'est donc finalement *[avoir du cul](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_du_cul#.C3.89tymologie)*. Quant à ce dernier

> Une étymologie populaire attribue l’origine de ce terme à l’argot des prisons, où les détenus qui acceptaient de se laisser sodomiser par les caïds, protégés par ceux-ci, étaient réputés avoir de la chance.<sup>[Wikt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_du_cul#.C3.89tymologie)</sup>

## Le cocu

Pour le cocu, le même wiktionnaire estime qu'ils n'ont de la chance que par antiphrase, sans plus de détails

> (Par antiphrase) Chanceux, veinard.<sup>[Wikt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocuhttps://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocu#Adjectif)</sup>

En revanche, [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr) le voit comme une manifestation de la [justice immanente](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9mis)

> l'idée est simple : elle part d'une tradition qui suppose que celui qui est frappé par le malheur d'être cocu ne peut décemment pas être toujours poursuivi par l'infortune. Alors en guise de compensation, il a le droit d'avoir beaucoup de chance.
>   Une veine de cocu s'utilise d'ailleurs beaucoup au jeu, et je vous rappelle qu'on dit aussi "heureux au jeu, malheureux en amour".<sup>[Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-une-veine-chance-de-cocu-pendu.php)</sup>

Parmi les autres étymologies populaires, on retrouve aussi souvent l'idée inverse : comme rien n'est jamais parfait, si quelqu'un a autant de chance, c'est qu'il y a un problème caché, qu'on suggère être un cocufiage — peut-être par jalousie, réelle ou feinte.

Answer (score 4):

*Bol* est ici un synonyme familier de *chance* (*pot* a aussi une acception semblable, mais je n'en connais pas l'origine).

Quant à savoir pourquoi les cocus doivent avoir plus de chance que les autres, je crois que c'est plutôt qu'il faut qu'ils en aient autant, et comme ce n'est pas dans le domaine amoureux qu'elle se trouve, ils en ont plus ailleurs.

Voir l'expression *heureux au jeu, malheureux en amour*.